# Is there a way to get RGB from gdal array and plot?

Tags: python, numpy, geospatial, raster, gdal

Problem:
I have a satellite image that contains multiple bands (i.e. MSI). I am process the image to extract bands, run clustering (KMeans), combine for indices (e.g. NDWI) but I cannot get a simple RGB output.

What I have tried:

```py
data = gdal.Open("myfile",gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
bands = [data.GetRasterBand(k + 1).ReadAsArray() for k in range(data.RasterCount)]
im = np.stack(bands, 2)

# attempt 1
rgb = im[:,:,[4,2,1]] #see first included image for output
plt.imshow(rgb)
plt.show()

# attempt 2
red = bands[4]
green = bands[2]
blue = bands [1]
rgb = np.zeros((red.shape[0],red.shape[1], 3))
rgb[:,:,0] = red
rgb[:,:,1] = green
rgb[:,:,2] = blue #see secondincluded image for output

plt.imshow((rgb * 255).astype(np.uint8))
```

In both cases, the image output is this odd green, and I am unsure why nor how to get it to display as RGB. Any thoughts?

[Attempt 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXhxd.png)

[Attempt 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrXik.png)

Comment: i would have expected the 4th band to be the alpha channel. Are you sure that it's the red channel?

Comment: Band [5] is Red, but - unless I am wrong, wouldnt the actual index be [4] since it begins at 0 when red by GDAL?

[1] CB, [2] B, [3] G, [4] Y, [5] R